# Проблема в записи и сравнении Json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, junit

```
@Test
void getAll() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = AbstractControllerTest.mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(REST_URL).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andReturn();
    assertEquals(result.getResponse().getStatus(), 200);
    String restaurantsJson = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    assertEquals(restaurantsJson, objectToJson(RESTAURANTS_ARRAY));
}

Expected :[{"id":100000,"name":"first restaurant","description":"fi re desc","meals":[{"name":"meal 1 re 1","id":100002,"price":100},{"name":"meal 2 re 1","id":100003,"price":200}]},{"id":100001,"name":"sec restaurant","description":"se re desc","meals":[{"name":"meal 1 re 2","id":100004,"price":300},{"name":"meal 2 re 2","id":100005,"price":400}]}]
Actual   :[{"name":"first restaurant","id":100000,"description":"fi re desc","meals":[{"name":"meal 1 re 1","id":100002,"price":100},{"name":"meal 2 re 1","id":100003,"price":200}]},{"name":"sec restaurant","id":100001,"description":"se re desc","meals":[{"name":"meal 1 re 2","id":100004,"price":300},{"name":"meal 2 re 2","id":100005,"price":400}]}]
```

Имеется тест, сравнивающий два джейсона, первый достается из `MvcResult`, а второй получается при записи массива через `ObjectMapper`. Записываемый объект имеет супер класс с параметром `name`, и по какой-то причине в первом случае на первое место в json ставится параметр `id`, а вот втором `name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие объекты, как Map не гарантируют порядок обхода ключей.

Соответственно при сериализации в json сериализатор может (или):

- просто обойти ключи в неопределенном порядке -- так быстрей
- отсортировать ключи предварительно, чтоб всегда получался одинаковый json
- предоставить возможность настроить одно из предидущих

Соответственно бы можете (или):

- понять, что четкий порядок у ключей есть и поменять тестовую строку
- настроить сериализатор
- заменить сериализатор

Подгонять строку под неизвестно что не советую, слетит в самый неподходящий момент.